# XSL split string on specific characters and apply processing (Example From DITA Open Toolkit Processing)

Tags: xml, xslt, transform, dita

I have this rule in my XSL already:

```
  <xsl:template match="title[starts-with(.,'Key Information for')]">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:attribute name="outputclass">Key Information Long</xsl:attribute>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*  | node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>
```

What it does:  add `outputclass='Key Information'` to `title` tags that start with "Key Information for" during pre-processing in the DITA Open Toolkit.

What I need to do is add an XPath to a match rule that finds other titles that fit this pattern:

```
<title>Some title text (More title text)</title>
```

My xsl xpath needs to identify the titles that end in text contained in parentheses and add some new tagging (`<ph aid:cstyle="parenthetical-subtitle">(More title text)</ph>` to that piece of the title.  When I add this rule, I also need to know how to integrate with the existing rule so it too gets the additional processing (and avoids an ambiguity conflict:  both the existing rule and the new one could apply to the same instance of content).

I was imagining an edit involving choose/when logic with the ends-with() function, but I hit the wall on exactly how to do this, and it turns out the toolkit version I am using only supports xml 1.0.  To illustrate --

If I have this input xml:

```
<section>
<title>Key Information for Our Test Process</title>
<p>Some stupid content.</p>
</section>
<section>
<title>Some Other Title</title>
<p>Other content.</p>
</section>
<section>
<title>Key Information for Testing (Stupid People Only)</title>
<p>Parentheses identify an audience which could really be anything.</p>
</section>
```

I want my edit to my rules to produce this output:

```
<section>
<title outputclass="Key Information Long">Key Information for Our Test Process</title>
<p>Some stupid content.</p>
</section>
<section>
<title>Some Other Title</title>
<p>Other content.</p>
</section>
<section>
<title outputclass="Key Information Long">Key Information for Testing <ph aid:cstyle="parenthetical-subtitle">(Stupid People Only)</ph></title>
<p>Parentheses identify an audience which could really be anything.</p>
</section>
```

Comment: 1. Does your processor support XSLT 2.0? 2. In case of conflict, which rule takes precedence?

Comment: @michael.hor257k, as `ends-with` is available to the poster, it is probably XSLT 2 or later.

Comment: @michael.hor257k - just edited my post.  Turns out I am only on xml 1.0 so ends-with is not available.  That's a bummer.

Comment: Just realized "what version" is not so easy to answer.  DITA Open Toolkit 2.7.2 (used in the plugin this is for) is using XML 1.0 but having a little difficulty finding the true xsl version.  I may just try the code on here and see what works and what doesn't work.  Thanks to all who posted (answers or comments).

Comment: @TMWP The last released DITA Open Toolkit 2.x is "DITA-OT 2.5.4". There is no "2.7.2" version. See https://www.dita-ot.org/download and confirm your DITA-OT version once again.

Comment: DITA-OT 2.x uses Saxon 9.1B as XSLT processor. So you can use XSLT 2.0 stylelsheets.

Comment: @TMWP You seem to misunderstand XSLT version with XML version.

Comment: Thanks for all of these comments.  I see now that I did confuse xml with xsl version.  I also double-checked, and the version is 2.5.2 of the toolkit so it sounds like xslt 2.0 should be supported.  Further tests got put on hold but will resume soon.  Really appreciate all the feedback.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If we can assume that the `title` element has no element children but solely plain text and you have an XSLT 2 or 3 processor as mentioning `ends-with` suggests you can match on the text node in the element and process it with `xsl:analyze-string`:

```
  <xsl:template match="title[starts-with(.,'Key Information for')]">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:attribute name="outputclass">Key Information Long</xsl:attribute>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*  | node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="title[starts-with(.,'Key Information for')]/text()">
      <xsl:analyze-string select="." regex="\(.*\)$">
          <xsl:matching-substring>
              <ph aid:cstyle="parenthetical-subtitle">
                  <xsl:value-of select="."/>
              </ph>
          </xsl:matching-substring>
          <xsl:non-matching-substring>
              <xsl:value-of select="."/>
          </xsl:non-matching-substring>
      </xsl:analyze-string>
  </xsl:template>
```

https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/6pS2B6n

Comment: This is very useful!

Answer (score 0):

You can identify a `title` that ends with text in parentheses (though not necessarily balanced parentheses) using this condition:

```
contains(., '(') and substring(., string-length(.))=')'
```

You could use this as the predicate in a separate template and give it a different priority than your existing template.